# Rails autoloading classes with the same name in class methods using singleton class syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

Let's say I have two classes with the same name ("Bar") in different modules (the global namespace / no namespace and "Foo") in a Rails application.
Both classes live in "app/models/bar.rb" or in "app/models/foo/bar.rb" respectively and are thereby autoloaded by rails.

```
# "app/models/foo/bar.rb"
module Foo
  class Bar
    def self.some_method
    end
  end
end

# "app/models/bar.rb"
class Bar
end
```

I have another class in the Foo namespace that uses the Bar class in a class method.

```
module Foo
  class Qux
    class << self
      def something
        Bar.some_method # This raises a NoMethod error because
                        # it uses the Bar defined in the global namespace
                        # and not the one in Foo
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rails autoloading tries to load Bar using the current classes `name`, which is `nil` in the singleton class, and defaults to "Object".

```
klass_name = name.presence || "Object"  # from active_support/dependencies.rb
```

This causes Rails to load `Bar` from "app/models/bar.rb" instead of "app/models/foo/bar.rb".
If I define `Qux.something` with `def self.something` then `.name` is "Foo::Qux" instead of nil and the autoloading works correctly.

I see 3 options for at the moment to work around this problem:

1) Rename one of the `Bar` classes
2) use the `self.` syntax everywhere
3) Namespace `Bar` with `Foo::Bar` explicitly everywhere

I don't like any of these options because:

1) `Bar` is just the name that fits the best
2) `class << self` is perfectly fine by itself and used by most ruby developers, so the chance is high that the next poor guy stumbles over the same issues again soon
3) Same as 2), it doesn't really fix the underlying "Problem" and somebody will waste some time in the future to figure out why his code doesn't work as expected.

Is there another, better option you can think of?

Comment: did you see this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lYR9WxIRH0 i think it covers some of your topics